Data fit to a circle using python
I am trying to fit a set of data to an off-center-circle using python. However, the displacement of the center of the circle (to the center of the axis) is evaluated negative, when it should be positive.

Consider a circle of radius a with center at (θ_0, r_0).
Therefore,

From this, I developed the following equations (I suppose everything is right):
Point (θ, r) on the circle:

Partial derivative of r with respect to a:

Partial derivative of r with respect to r_0:

Partial derivative of r with respect to θ_0:

This is a MWE:
import numpy as np               #... for mathematical operations and constants
from scipy import optimize       #... for data fitting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #... for plots


dsts = [1.0238822745042868, 1.0179614005977726, 1.0288142236514832, 1.014240255062302, 1.0297548330833965]
angs = [1.2118767129907884, 0.46576418683129606, -0.2945355605442553, 0.7614519513889376, -0.7442328029712463]


#--> DEFINE FUNCTIONS TO FIT THE DATA
#... see: https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/non-linear-fitting-to-an-ellipse/

def circle(theta, p): #... defines the function for circle
    a, r0, theta_0 = p
    rc = r0*np.cos(theta - theta_0)
    return ( rc + (rc**2 + a**2 - r0**2)**0.5 )

def residuals(p, r, theta):
    """ Return the observed - calculated residuals using f(theta, p). """
    return r - circle(theta, p)

def jac(p, r, theta):
    """ Calculate and return the Jacobian of residuals. """
    tmp = circle(theta, p)
    a, r0, theta_0 = p
    da  = a/( tmp - r0*np.cos(theta - theta_0) )
    dr  = ( r*np.cos(theta - theta_0) - r0 )/( r - r0*np.cos(theta - theta_0) )
    dt  = tmp*r0*np.sin(theta - theta_0)/( tmp - r0*np.cos(theta - theta_0) )
    
    return -da,  -dr, -dt
    return np.array((-da, -dr, -dt)).T


#--> FIT THE DATA
p0 = (1, 0.05, 0) #... initial guess
plsq = optimize.leastsq(residuals, p0, Dfun=jac, args=(dsts, angs), col_deriv=True)


#--> CREATE FITTING CURVE ARRAYS
t_fit = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r_fit = circle(t_fit, plsq[0])


#--> PLOT
cm = 1/2.54  #... centimeters-to-inches conversor
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'}, figsize=(8.5*cm, 8.5*cm), dpi=300)

#--> Write the title
fit_a = str(round(plsq[0][0], 4))
fit_r = str(round(plsq[0][1], 4))
fit_t = str(round(plsq[0][2]*180/np.pi, 1))
pltTitle = "$a =$" + fit_a + "; $r_0 =$ " + fit_r + "; $\\theta_0 =$ " + fit_t + "$^\circ$"
ax.set_title(pltTitle, va='bottom', fontsize=8)

#--> Plot the measured data
ax.scatter(angs, dsts)

#--> Plot the fitted orbit
ax.plot(t_fit, r_fit, linestyle='dotted')

#--> Configure the axis
ax.set_rmax(1.2)
ax.set_rticks(np.linspace(0.2, 1, 5))
ax.set_xticklabels([])      #... remove angular tick labels
ax.set_yticklabels([])      #... remove radial tick labels
ax.grid(True)

#--> Display the plot
plt.show()

Any suggestion to get positive r_0?

Something seems off about your circle equation. For sufficiently circles that do not intercept the x-axis, your equation still gives a valid distance for theta = 0.
Additionally, when I plot your equation, the a parameter does not seem to control the circle radius properly.

How do all your partial derivatives have rs in them? Your r equation is explicit, so your partial derivatives should only be functions of the independent variables.

@MichaelCao, I just edited the question by adding a figure and the initial equation to clarify the remaining information.

@jared I just edited the question and added a figure and the initial (vector) equation. The derivatives I made from the very first equation, which is much simpler. If you prefer, you can replace $r$ by the second equation and stay with constants only.

@Brasil Be aware that LaTeX doesn't work on this site, so the dollar signs only make things more difficult to read.

@jared thank you for the advise. I just wrote as I do in tex.stackexchange.com. How should I proceed here to display math?

@Brasil Clear photos of LaTeX for the equations (like you have) is fine. For online stuff, just using r_0 or theta_0 is clear enough. The dollar signs just make things a bit harder to read (it makes the text busier).

Clear photos work if watching the site in bright mode. On dark mode you have black text on top of a very dark gray background.

After examining your problem a bit closer I realized that
there is in fact nothing wrong with your results!
Your problem just has an ambiguity with respect to r_0 and theta_0.
r( r0, theta_0 )  = r( -r0, theta_0 + [2n+1]pi )

Proper boundary conditions (or close enough start-values) should do the job just fine!
Alternatively you can also just "sanitize" the obtained results by applying something like:
def sanitize_results(a, r0, theta0):
    if r0 < 0:
        return a, -r0, (theta0 + np.pi)%(2*np.pi)
    else:
        return a, r0, theta0%(2*np.pi)



UPDATE
To use explicit boundary-conditions in the least-squares solver, you have to switch to the newer scipy interface, e.g.: scipy.optimize.least_squares
plsq = least_squares(
    residuals, 
    p0, 
    jac=jac, 
    args=(dsts, angs),
    bounds=((0, 0, 0), (10, 10, 2*np.pi))
    )

the obtained parameter values are then accessible via
plsq.x

... and a final warning:
Your sketch is actually a bit misleading... your equation will only work if the center of the coordinate-system is inside the circle! ...otherwise your equation is not valid for all 360° (e.g. there is more than 1 possible solution for r given a set of parameters (a, r0, thata0)

This comforts me. I am not with my pc now to test. Do you know how to apply bounds so that the fitting always provides r > 0?

Hey @Brasil, I've updated my answer to show you how to use boundaries with scipy.optimize.least_squares.

Hey @raphael thank your for the advise. I just updated the question. There was a sign missplaced in the equation (2) r(θ). Now I think everything is right.

Yep you're right :-)

Performed it in cartesian by converting coordinates then calculating r0, theta0 from there. Too lazy to manually calculate the Jacobian, so let the leastsq function estimate that.
For the error, I used the difference in distance from the supposed center versus the supposed radius.
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np

dsts = [1.0238822745042868, 1.0179614005977726, 1.0288142236514832, 1.014240255062302, 1.0297548330833965]
angs = [1.2118767129907884, 0.46576418683129606, -0.2945355605442553, 0.7614519513889376, -0.7442328029712463]

x = dsts*np.cos(angs)
y = dsts*np.sin(angs)

def error(params):
    x0, y0, a = params
    return np.linalg.norm([x - x0, y - y0], axis = 0) - r

[x0, y0, a], _ = leastsq(error, [0, 0, 5])

r0 = np.linalg.norm([x0, y0])
theta0 = np.angle(x0 + 1j*y0)

# Plot fit
theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)

xfit = x0 + r*np.cos(theta)
yfit = y0 + r*np.sin(theta)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xfit, yfit)
plt.scatter(x, y)


Numerical example of circular fitting with your data :

In this particular case the center of the fitted circle (a,b) is close to the origin. Of course the method works as well in cases of center far from the origin. Your data isn't scattered. The method works as well with scattered data.
Ref. :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique , Section 7, pp.11-15.
